# Schema markup: WebPage vs Article

Tags: markup, schema.org, structured-data

I'm providing a website about my health-related services, with a few pages describing my practice and services, my approach of work, and many articles about specific topics related to my field of work (imagine what a doctor or therapist is doing, that should give the idea).

But I'm confused whether to define my pages as "Webpage" or "Article"?

I defined them as 'Article' now, which in turn disallows me from tagging my phone number with
`<span itemprop="telephone">` 
though, according to Google's Structured Data testing tool.

Comment: Your questions aren’t closely related, so it doesn’t makes sense to have them in one post. Most would be duplicates anyway: See my answers  [about the `id` issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29492058/1591669), [about `publisher`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39955571/1591669), [about multiple properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669), and [about `headline`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38001407/1591669). So this leaves the question about `WebPage` vs. `Article`. To keep this open, I would suggest to make your question post about this one (ideally including example markup).

Comment: done, thanks for the other references, all my other issues/questions have been answered by that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the typical case, you would use both. You could provide a `WebPage` item on every page, and if the web page contains an article, you could provide an `Article` item in addition (or multiple, of course).

For a page dedicated to an article, you could use the [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) property to denote that the `Article` is the primary thing on that page:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  </article>
</body>
```

Neither a web page nor an article can have a telephone number (at least not in typical cases, which is why Schema.org doesn’t define the `telephone` property for `WebPage`/`Article`). A telephone number typically belongs to a person or an organization, which are among the types that can have the [`telephone`](http://schema.org/telephone) property.

So you need an item that represents your business: in your case probably [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness). Then you can provide this item as [`author`](http://schema.org/author) of the `WebPage` and/or the `Article` etc.

PS: Whenevery you use a type, check if a more specific child type applies in your case. So in your case maybe something like [`MedicalWebPage`](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/MedicalWebPage), [`NewsArticle`](http://schema.org/NewsArticle), [`HealthAndBeautyBusiness`](http://schema.org/HealthAndBeautyBusiness), etc.

Comment: FYI, Google's Structured Data Testing Tool complains "The mainEntityOfPage field is recommended. Please provide a value if available." about the snippet above. It doesn't even change if I replace "mainEntity" with "mainEntityOfPage".

Comment: @richey: Yes, that’s a problem with Google’s tool/guide: the markup in my answer means exactly the same (it’s just using the inverse property), but Google seems to only recognize the other one. See [my answer about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36117597/1591669). If you want to please Google’s tool, you can place this inside of the `Article`: `<link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="" />` (where `href` takes the URL of the current page, so it could stay empty; but to be on the safe side, you could provide the canonical URL of the page explicitly).