# How to mark up the text of a legal act with "Legislation"?

Tags: schema.org

For legal documents markup I was using `Article` as there was no schema for legal documents.

Now I want to change markup to [`Legislation`](http://schema.org/Legislation) schema. But I could not find a property in `Legislation` schema similar to `articleBody` in `Article` schema.

How is it possible to mark up the text of the legal act with `Legislation` schema?

Comment: To markup the legal act's text I've used "text" property of CreativeWork. But I'm not sure it's a good solution.

Comment: Why shouldn’t `text` be a good solution?

Comment: There was a property articleBody for Article schema instead of text property. So maybe there should be a new property instead of "text" for Legislation? And which property we should use for law's headline markup - headline or name?

Comment: Regarding `headline`, [see the this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38001407/1591669).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the whole text, use the [`text` property](http://schema.org/text):

> The textual content of this CreativeWork.

It seems to match your use case. The fact that another type has another property that could make sense (`Article` with `articleBody`) shouldn’t be relevent for the decision to use `text` for `Legislation`.

If your legal document is *also* an article, you could use both types (`Article` and `Legislation`) together. In that case you could use `articleBody` in addition to, or instead of, `text`.¹

---

¹ It’s not really clear if or how `articleBody` and `text` are different. Related issue: [articleBody and text](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/351)